# Where do you find slime chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need slimes for sticky pistons but I can't find any slimes. I heard that slime chunks are the best way of getting slimes but I can't find any. Is there a good way to find slime. (I have already used slime chunks finder websites but since I have  random seed its really hard to tell where they are)

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to find a slime chunk is to go underground below Y-40 and create tunnels big enough to spawn small and medium slimes. A trick that you can do is to click the key combination f3+Q followed by f3+G. This will show chunk boundaries. After tunneling through long enough, you should be able to find a chunk that can spawn slimes. Remember that slimes count towards the mob count, and if there are too many other monsters in the area, then slimes will not spawn. Once you find a chunk, you can expand the space in the chunk to spawn all types of slimes.

Comment: F3 + Q is not needed to go first, it just prints the help, once you know the command you can use it like F3 + G, also this only works on java

Comment: @Joe Cabezas it's fine that it only works on java since the question is for java.

Comment: I am saying that F3+Q step is not needed

Comment: How big a tunnel?